# Excel Userform Textbox Value Not Updating When Changed

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, userform

I have been scratching my head on this for a while now and after a lot of Google searches I have not found an answer.  I am just learning how to write this stuff, so sorry in advance if this is basic stuff I should already know.  Basically what I am doing is populating a userform with data from a spreadsheet.  The user selects a value from a combobox and then the corresponding data from the spreadsheet is populated in textboxes on the form.  The user can then edit those textboxes and save the changes, but no changes are being saved.  For some reason the value of the textbox does not change from the original value even though the text in the textbox has been changed.  My code is posted below.  The first block is the code used to populate the textboxes when the combobox is changed.  That portion works fine.  The second block is the code used to save the new data and that is what is not working.

```
Private Sub PartToEdit_Change()

Dim lngDataRow As Long
lngDataRow = EditPartForm.PartToEdit.ListIndex + 1

EditPartForm.Customer.Value = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(lngDataRow, 2) 'customer name
EditPartForm.Color.Value = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(lngDataRow, 4) 'color
EditPartForm.PartNumber.Value = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(lngDataRow, 1) 'part number
EditPartForm.Desc.Value = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(lngDataRow, 3) 'description
EditPartForm.Step1.Value = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(lngDataRow, 5) 'step 1
EditPartForm.Step2.Value = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(lngDataRow, 6) 'step 2
EditPartForm.Step3.Value = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(lngDataRow, 7) 'step 3
EditPartForm.Step4.Value = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(lngDataRow, 8) 'step 4
EditPartForm.Step5.Value = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(lngDataRow, 9) 'step 5
EditPartForm.Step6.Value = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(lngDataRow, 10) 'step 6
EditPartForm.Step7.Value = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(lngDataRow, 11) 'step 7
EditPartForm.Step8.Value = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(lngDataRow, 12) 'step 8
EditPartForm.Step9.Value = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(lngDataRow, 13) 'step 9
EditPartForm.Step10.Value = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(lngDataRow, 14) 'step 10
EditPartForm.BlastTime.Value = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(lngDataRow, 15) 'blast time
EditPartForm.PrepTime.Value = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(lngDataRow, 16) 'prep time
EditPartForm.PaintTime.Value = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(lngDataRow, 17) 'paint time
EditPartForm.BakeTime.Value = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(lngDataRow, 18) 'bake time
EditPartForm.PartNotes.Value = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(lngDataRow, 19) 'special notes
EditPartForm.PicPath.Value = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(lngDataRow, 20) 'picture path

End Sub

Private Sub SavePartButton_Click()

Dim lngDataRow As Long
lngDataRow = EditPartForm.PartToEdit.ListIndex + 1

Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & lngDataRow).Value = EditPartForm.PartNumber.Text 'part number
Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B" & lngDataRow).Value = EditPartForm.Customer.Text 'customer
Sheets("Sheet3").Range("C" & lngDataRow).Value = EditPartForm.Desc.Text 'description
Sheets("Sheet3").Range("D" & lngDataRow).Value = EditPartForm.Color.Text 'color
Sheets("Sheet3").Range("E" & lngDataRow).Value = EditPartForm.Step1.Text 'step 1
Sheets("Sheet3").Range("F" & lngDataRow).Value = EditPartForm.Step2.Text 'step 2
Sheets("Sheet3").Range("G" & lngDataRow).Value = EditPartForm.Step3.Text 'step 3
Sheets("Sheet3").Range("H" & lngDataRow).Value = EditPartForm.Step4.Text 'step 4
Sheets("Sheet3").Range("I" & lngDataRow).Value = EditPartForm.Step5.Text 'step 5
Sheets("Sheet3").Range("J" & lngDataRow).Value = EditPartForm.Step6.Text 'step 6
Sheets("Sheet3").Range("K" & lngDataRow).Value = EditPartForm.Step7.Text 'step 7
Sheets("Sheet3").Range("L" & lngDataRow).Value = EditPartForm.Step8.Text 'step 8
Sheets("Sheet3").Range("M" & lngDataRow).Value = EditPartForm.Step9.Text 'step 9
Sheets("Sheet3").Range("N" & lngDataRow).Value = EditPartForm.Step10.Text 'step 10
Sheets("Sheet3").Range("O" & lngDataRow).Value = EditPartForm.BlastTime.Text 'blast time
Sheets("Sheet3").Range("P" & lngDataRow).Value = EditPartForm.PrepTime.Text 'prep time
Sheets("Sheet3").Range("Q" & lngDataRow).Value = EditPartForm.PaintTime.Text 'paint time
Sheets("Sheet3").Range("R" & lngDataRow).Value = EditPartForm.BakeTime.Text 'bake time
Sheets("Sheet3").Range("S" & lngDataRow).Value = EditPartForm.PartNotes.Text 'part notes
Sheets("Sheet3").Range("T" & lngDataRow).Value = EditPartForm.PicPath.Text 'picture path

Unload EditPartForm

End Sub
```

If I manually change the data by using something like the code below, it updates just fine.

```
Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & lngDataRow).Value = "Some Value"
```

Please help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to put a breakpoint in and see if it actually execute?
Also check in your 'watch' while you are debugging that the values it write is the values you want it to write.

In my projects I use:

```
Sheet.Cells(row, col).value = value
```

Comment: I did try your suggestion of adding a breakpoint.  I can check the value of any of the textboxes and the value shows the edited text, but when I go to write the edited data to the spreadsheet it is not updating the spreadsheet.  My issue has to somewhere in the lines that are resaving the data.  Especially because I can manually update the sheet by using a line like this...`Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & lngDataRow).Value = "Some Value"`

Comment: I wonder if there is not something blocking it from writing data? Is this from a control, or formula? I know Formulas can't change data in other cells